# Can i remove the virus from website scripts from unix shell

Tags: centos, malware

My website is infected with iframe injection and some javascript virus.

There is some JS code which is present in all the files.

Is there any way that i can paste that JS code in a text file and make shell script which matches that pattern and rmoves from the pages

I have vps server centos with cpanel whm

Comment: The question "my site/server has been hacked/infected" comes up all the time, the answer is always the same: **"Wipe the server, restore from known-good backups"**

Comment: See the somewhat related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182756/remove-line-of-text-from-multiple-files-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

If the site is infected it would be safer to replace everything from a clean backup - and that includes any databases you might have.

While it probably is possible there's a good chance you'll miss something and not have a fully clean site.

You should also try and work out where the infection came from - probably an insecure ftp account - and close that loophole before proceeding.

Comment: the problem is i don't have backup at all , what should i do

Comment: is there any scanner available for website which can delete the malaciou code via ftp